# What is the value of $\sup {a_n}?$

Tags: real-analysis

Define  the  sequence  $\{a_n\}$  as  follows  : $a_1 =1 $ and  for  $n \ge 1$  ,$$a_{n+1}= (-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \left( |a_n|  + \frac{2}{|a_n|}\right).$$ What is the  value of  $\sup {a_n}?$

**My attempt** : let $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = l$

then  $$l = \frac{1}{2} \left( l + \frac{2}{l}\right) \implies  l =\pm\sqrt 2$$

since $a_1 =1 \implies  l = \sqrt {2}$

Therefore  $\sup {a_n}=\sqrt {2}$

Am I right or wrong?

Comment: $\sup a_n$ isn't the same as $\lim a_n,$ even when $\lim a_n$ exists. It would be different if the question asked for $\limsup a_n.$ In any event, you've only shown that if the limit exists, you know the value. But that doesn't work if the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: okay @ThomasAndrews I think in this  case  $\lim \sup a_n = \sup a_n$

Comment: In any event, the alternation of signs means we can only get a limit for $|a_n|,$ unless $a_n\to0.$

Comment: AM/GM says that $|a_n|>\sqrt2,$ so for even $n,$ you have all $a_n>\sqrt2.$ So $\sqrt2$ is not the supremum

Comment: It is true that $\limsup a_n=\sqrt2,$ but that is not the question you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we have some mistakes here.

First, if we assume $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {a_n} = l$. Then we have $l = \frac{1}{2}\left( {\left| l \right| + \frac{2}{{\left| l \right|}}} \right)$.

Second, we CAN NOT use the sign of the first element to conclude the sign of the limit of a sequence.

Next, we need to find sup, we do not find lim sup. So I think this direction is totally wrong.

In fact, by computing some elements of the sequence, you can easily discover that $\mathop {\sup }\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} {a_n} = \mathop {\max }\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} {a_n} = \frac{17}{12}$.

Comment: $\frac{3}{2}$ is not in the sequence. $a_2 = -\frac{3}{2}$ and $a_3 = \frac{17}{12}$.

Comment: Yeah. The true answer is 17/12. I have a mistake in computation.

Comment: @TrầnQuangMinh you can fix a wrong answer...